# Problems with AsyncTask and updating UI with ProgressUpdate and Listeners

Tags: android, listener, android-asynctask

I am getting a "CalledFromWrongThreadException" error when I try to update a TextView (via a listener) from an AsyncTask onProgressUpdate.

If I try to update the same TextView from onPostExecute everything works.

I have been testing using code based on 
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherAPI

(with a small mod that does an onProgressUpdate in the doInBackgroundMethod, and adds the onProgressUpdate override)

Any suggestion to fixes would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code (relevant parts)

Comment: You must not call onProgressUpdate from doInBackground. By doing so, you run it on the background thread and can't update views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you calling `onProgressUpdate()` from your code? You shouldn't do it. Use [`publishProgress()`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) method.

Comment: I read that in the SDK and still did it wrong anyway. ARGH! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`onProgressUpdate` doesn't run on UI thread, so you can't access views from this method. If you want to update progress, you should find a way to synchronize your `AsyncTask` with your activity. A way that I'm using is to create an interface with methods like `onBegin`, `onUpdate` and `onFinish`. You should implement this interface in your main activity class. Then you should have an instance of your activity inside your `AsyncTask`. In the `onProgressUpdate` method you just call the onUpdate method in your activity and update the layout. Hope I've explained it clear enough.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov - If onProgressUpdate() is in the UI thread, shouldn't this work? (MainActivity.java http://ideone.com/AzwOCk and activity_main.xml http://ideone.com/ryWMma). I get "Unfortunately App has stopped". Here is the output: http://ideone.com/shwENk - I'm very new to Java as well as Android, but that looks to me like it can't find the UI element (as if it were not in the same thread perhaps?).